# Making a Chrome extension using WebSharper

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, websharper

Is it possible to use WebSharper's F# to JavaScript compiler to build a Google Chrome extension?

My research tells me the Single-Page App template should be enough to write extension code. However, I require access to Chrome API, for which no WebSharper type bindings exist. There are [TypeScript bindings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/chrome), which could help me write WebSharper bindings manually, but is there a way to generate WebSharper bindings from existing TypeScript bindings?

Comment: Did you get around to bind the Chrome API?

Comment: No, I left it at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have no public tool for generating bindings from `.d.ts` just an internal one for WebSharper 3, but it's a bit outdated, does not recognize some newer syntax. We have plans for reintroducing TypeScript support for WebSharper 4, but no ETA yet, sorry.